# Unable to ping the remote user via ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, redhat, ansible

**I'm trying to connect my host machine which is of Ubuntu (ctrlnode is user) to remote machine which is of RHEL (rhelnode1 is user) on AWS and when I try to connect my a user (rhelnode1) on remote machine it show error msg "Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password)"**

- I have changed the config file (rhelnode1)for the ssh server and restart the server
- I have added the remote user (rhelnode1) in VISUDO file
- I have added my  host machine (ctrlnode) public key in remote machine 
  (rhelnode1)  with the permission (700) for ".ssh" and (600) for "authorized_keys"

```
ctrlnode@ip--XX-XX-XXX:~$ cd .ssh
**ctrlnode@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX:~/.ssh$ cat id_rsa.pub** 
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDATfN6+GAr+XTt/qW8YxS1mBZSXHiaoOnH5iDcVkGbylHORZyOjpxpQtbBFV3LoeAmwudz6mhEgd2JTt5UzBU7Hbz0qkKVjb+4R1iiHQlqoGs57MyHBdoiYnNVThyRbS9nIOseMPK5vdYr8OhPawPV9IqhWl6j1oWVNRd7olbPzUccsrAfrmUxI9cNI+c2m6ZqzEdCvb2DtklHM6tBL9J0oOoT2BHvatZd58WKoJnKh9z2Om/ymwTq4FMRxZszhoskhqXA6s9GFnManWeFpgaF+wZlp0YG1zrKyKSkqoBWxayZOFSAJJeMQAkkczwo/M0B8KXHbkXtQ1tfVLCTT8Pr ctrlnode@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX
ctrlnode@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX:~/.ssh$ 
ctrlnode@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX:~/.ssh$ cd ..
**ctrlnode@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX:~$ ssh rhelnode1@XX-XX-XX-XXX**
rhelnode1@XX-XX-XX-XXX's password: 
Last login: Wed Feb 13 09:51:37 2019 from ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.internal
[rhelnode1@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ 
[rhelnode1@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ 
[rhelnode1@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ ls -la .ssh/
total 4
drwx------. 2 rhelnode1 rhelnode1  29 Feb 10 06:01 .
drwx------. 4 rhelnode1 rhelnode1 127 Feb 10 06:23 ..
-rw-------. 1 rhelnode1 rhelnode1 406 Feb 10 06:01 authorized_keys
[rhelnode1@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ cd .ssh
**[rhelnode1@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX .ssh]$ cat authorized_keys** 
sh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDATfN6+GAr+XTt/qW8YxS1mBZSXHiaoOnH5iDcVkGbylHORZyOjpxpQtbBFV3LoeAmwudz6mhEgd2JTt5UzBU7Hbz0qkKVjb+4R1iiHQlqoGs57MyHBdoiYnNVThyRbS9nIOseMPK5vdYr8OhPawPV9IqhWl6j1oWVNRd7olbPzUccsrAfrmUxI9cNI+c2m6ZqzEdCvb2DtklHM6tBL9J0oOoT2BHvatZd58WKoJnKh9z2Om/ymwTq4FMRxZszhoskhqXA6s9GFnManWeFpgaF+wZlp0YG1zrKyKSkqoBWxayZOFSAJJeMQAkkczwo/M0B8KXHbkXtQ1tfVLCTT8Pr ctrlnode@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX
[rhelnode1@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX .ssh]$ cd ..
[rhelnode1@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX ~]$ ls -la
total 20
drwx------. 4 rhelnode1 rhelnode1  127 Feb 10 06:23 .
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root      root        39 Feb  7 08:43 ..
drwx------. 3 rhelnode1 rhelnode1   17 Feb 10 06:23 .ansible
-rw-------. 1 rhelnode1 rhelnode1 1947 Feb 13 09:53 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--. 1 rhelnode1 rhelnode1   18 May 22  2018 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--. 1 rhelnode1 rhelnode1  193 May 22  2018 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--. 1 rhelnode1 rhelnode1  231 May 22  2018 .bashrc
**drwx------. 2 rhelnode1 rhelnode1   29 Feb 10 06:01 .ssh**
```

**Actual output**

**when I try to ping the remote machine (rhelnode1) it show**

```
my ctrlnode@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~$ ansible -m ping web1 -vv -K
    ansible 2.7.6
      config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
      configured module search path = [u'/home/ctrlnode/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
      ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
      executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
      python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]
    Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
    SUDO password: 
    /etc/ansible/hosts did not meet host_list requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
    /etc/ansible/hosts did not meet script requirements, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected
    META: ran handlers
    web1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
        "changed": false, 
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: rhelnode1@xxx.xx.xx.xx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", 
        "unreachable": true
```

**Here we go,when I do normal ssh here is the output**

```
ctrlnode@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX:~$ ssh rhelnode1@XXX.XX.XX.XX -vvv
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "172.31.28.59" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.31.28.59 [172.31.28.59] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 172.31.28.59:22 as 'rhelnode1'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ctrlnode/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 172.31.28.59
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:w9M1+cFv0rbxejLMIflyYxeH7YH+Zopp/uZ2JkDrIEA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ctrlnode/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from XXX.XX.XX.XX
debug1: Host '172.31.28.59' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_rsa (0x56113dd7eb30)
debug2: key: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:dVjr8XK2ga8RdRl1PlsiTz7qBrEGL+cy2CpNXAegHic /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
rhelnode1@XXX.XX.XX.XX's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to XXX.XX.XX.XX ([XXX.XX.XX.XX]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug1: Sending env LANG = C.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Wed Feb 13 06:59:33 2019
[rhelnode1@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
[rhelnode1@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a ping and the exact ssh command line you use. When I connect to ubuntu instances on AWS I think I use ubuntu@1.2.3.4 along with my private key file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorized_keys is for incoming connections. It's to auth the user's incoming connection.

> The authorized_keys file in SSH specifies the SSH keys that can be used for logging into the user account for which the file is configured.

So basically: The login attempt is accepted by the remote server if the user can prove that he knows the private key, the public key is in the account's authorization list `(~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server)`

Can you share the output of a manual ssh attempt (but verbose output) to the remote host:

`ssh rhelnode1@xxx.xx.xx.xx -vvv`

**Edit:**

To ensure all permissions for all the files on the remote machine are correct, use `ssh-copy-id user@device` You will be prompted for a password, but once you're successfully authenticated, the next SSH attempt will use the SSH keys added.

Comment: I have shared the output of a manaual ssh attempt @relevantRope

Comment: thanks... Do you have the cntrlnode's public key added to rhelnode1's authorized_keys file on the remote host?

Comment: yes, I have added public key of ctrlnode to rhelnode1's authorizes_keys and I request you to look my edited content once again @relevantRope

Comment: yes. I see thanks. To ensure all permissions for all the files on the remote machine are correct, try `ssh-copy-id user@device` it will prompt for a password, but once you're successfully authenticated, the keys can be used.

Comment: Thank you ..!!! After running #ssh-copy-idusernam@device I'm able to ping the remote user sucessfully and can you tell me why it was unsucessfull ping when I added the public key (manual proccedure)?? @relevantRope

Comment: Glad to hear. SSH keys need to be exact, and rightfully so. I'm guessing it was an unintentional error when copying the keys over. If you had copied an extra space or a carriage return, the keys won't match and will be rejected. Using `ssh-copy-id` we ensure that keys are added correctly, with the correct file and user permissions

Answer (score 0):

As per logs "no such identity: /home/ctrlnode/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory" you did not copy public key of user "ctrlnode" to target machine properly. Copy public kye in authorized_keys file under /home/rhelnode1/.ssh folder.

Comment: yes I have seen the debug message but I have added  I have added public key of ctrlnode to rhelnode1's authorizes_keys. @sunil

Comment: try to re-add it. Maybe while copying key you missed some characters. and share the result of #ssh -vvvv -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey rhelnode1@server_IP once.

Comment: Thank you ..!! For the help, now I can ping the remote user after re-adding it via #shh-copy-id username@remote_user. Next time I'll avoid the manual process